# How can I permanently delete my Yahoo mail account?

Tags: account-management, yahoo-mail

How can I permanently delete a Yahoo mail account?

Also, what will happen to any messages sent to this address?

Comment: Have you tried the answer given here? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/653/service-to-delete-any-web-app-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used service [deleteyouraccount](http://deleteyouraccount.com) (quite useful not only for yahoo :) ). However your account will be removed only after 3 months.

Comment: http://deleteyouraccount.com/sites/yahoo
I agree, very useful :)
The three month time is rather annoying though.